# How to find the position of letters in a list of words?

Tags: python-2.7

In a list of words :

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

for e.g.:How do I find the position of an 'A'; it could be any 'A'

Comment: > It could be any 'A' -- `__import_('random').choice(list_of_words).find('A')`

(that is to say - can you be more specific about the constraints?)

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_A(input):
    for i, c in enumerate(input):
        if c == 'A': yield i
```

will return the character position of all the As